# Python- Validating User Input

Tags: string, python-3.x, validation, int

My code needs to validate user input to make sure they enter a number and keep looping until they enter a number.

My code:

```
user_input=input("Enter a number: ")
while user_input != int:
    user_input=input("Error: Enter a number: ")
```

My Output:

Enter a number: d

Error: Enter a number: f

Error: Enter a number: 5

Error: Enter a number: 5

Error: Enter a number: 3

Why doesnt it even accept numbers?

Comment: May be all you want is `user_input.isnumeric()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

I think the piece of code below solves your problem in a way that is easily understood.

```
user_input = input("Enter a number: ")
while not user_input.isnumeric():
    user_input = input("Error: Enter a number: ")
```

**Explanation**

The code you have didn't work because of `while user_input != int`.

When you call the `input` function, and the user provides an input, that input is always a string.

```
>>> num = input('Enter a number: ') # 5, as a string
>>> num
'5'
```

Your intent is to check if `num` is a number. So, to check if a string represents some number, you can use the `str.isdigit()`, `str.isdecimal()`, and `str.isnumeric()` methods. You can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

It's easy to mistakenly believe the following approach is viable, but it can quickly get messy.

```
while not isinstance(user_input, int):
```

Remember, the input you receive as a result of calling the `input` function will be a string. Therefore, the code above will always be True, which is not what you want. Though, the code above could work if you change `user_input` to be of type `int`.

```
>>> num = input('Enter a number: ') # 5, as a string
>>> num
'5'
>>> int(num)
5
>>> isinstance(num, int)
True
```

But the interpreter would throw an error if `num` was something else.

```
>>> num = input('Enter a number: ') # 'A'
>>> int(num)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'
```

This brings us back to the answer, which involves using a string method to check if the string represents some number. I chose to use the `str.isnumeric()` method because it is the most flexible.

I hope this answers your question. Happy coding!